# Call specific cache with ajax on laravel

Tags: json, ajax, laravel, caching

So I gonna try to be clear.

I had make graph using `d3.js` , all works perfectly.
After I had put creation of json in cache for better performance, now when a user want to see his graph I have a function like this.

```
public function barGraph()
{
    $idUser = Auth::user()->id;

    $data=Cache::get($idUser+'100');

    //envoi du json
    if (count($data)) {
        return $data;
    } else {
        return ['Pas de données pour ce graph'];
    }

}
```

That call the cache properly and display the graph.
But now I want that the user can change the graph, like he is an other user.

I have make a select like this...

```
<select name="things" id="things" class="form-control littleSelect">
    <option selected disabled>La liste de vos hotels</option>
    @foreach($listings as $listing)
        <option value="{{ $listing->idThing}}">{{ $listing->nameThing }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Who send a parameter to my function like that :

```
 $('#things').on('change', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'barGraph',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { id: this.value },
        success: function (response) {
            $( '#chart' ).load( response );
        },
        dataType: 'html'
    });
})
```

I try to get this parameter in my function like this :

```
public function barGraph()
{
    if (Request::ajax()) {
        $isUser= Input::get("id");
        $data=Cache::get($isUser+'100');
        return $data;
    } else {
        $idUser = Auth::user()->id;
    }

    $data=Cache::get($idUser+'100');

    if (count($data)) {
        return $data;
    } else {
        return ['Pas de données pour ce graph'];
    }
}
```

The problem is when I make a choice on my select.
The chart disappear, and I see the json for the first chart, not for the choice chart.

Anyone have an idea of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I don't understand. Are the `$listing->idThing` supposed to be user ids?

Comment: Yes that's it , and i want to take this info , for send to my function and display the good chart for this user

Comment: So that would mean that any user can see charts intended to be for other users?

Comment: No all this page is protected by a middleware , and its only display for SpecialUsers ,and $listings is only charts from users we allow him to see.

Comment: I think there's going to be a problem though if the user you're trying to get the chart of has not logged in to generate the chart yet. Perhaps have a fallback function to generate it if there's a cache miss.

Comment: All caches for all the users are generated each night so all the data is already present. I don't know why he don't want to take this cache.

Comment: My only other idea is that you should examine your cache and make sure the keys are as you expect them to be.